# a series of points, any definition?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Giving a series of points $P_k=\{(X_k,Y_k)\}$ let $P_o=(X_0,Y_0)$

What does it mean that $lim P_k=P_0$ (is there any definition using $\epsilon$)?

Comment: Use the standard $\epsilon - \delta$ definition with Euclidean distance instead of absolute values.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then using the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$d\big((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\big)=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2},$$
we say that:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}(X_k,Y_k)=(X_0,Y_0)$$
if and only if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $k\geq k_0$, we have:
$$d\big((X_k,Y_k),(X_0,Y_0)\big)=\sqrt{(X_k-X_0)^2+(Y_k-Y_0)^2}<\varepsilon.$$
This is very analogous to the case of a convergent sequence of values in $\mathbb{R}$ - the only difference is that we have changed our metric (i.e. "distance function") from the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}$ given by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ to the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^2$.